# Genderize names - request limit reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a dataset of names that I want to put through the Genderize package. I did about 500 names two days ago which worked find but since then it won't let me do anymore.

I've tried just doing one name and it still has the same error message as when I use a csv file.

This is my code:

```
from genderize import Genderize
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
names = df['FirstName']
```

The error message is:

> GenderizeException: ('Request limit reached', 429, {'Server':
>   'nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)', 'Date': 'Thu, 25 Jul 2019 13:03:38 GMT',
>   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length':
>   '33', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':
>   'Content-Type', 'ETag': 'W/"21-tYoIBroDGdB+35cIAOMCdpXfqjI"'})

As far as I'm aware (from the website - genderize.io) it says the limit is 1000 names a day which I've not reached - I've not done any today and only did about 500 two days ago.

Does anyone know what the reason for this could be?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `X-Rate-` Headers as indicated in the documentation ( https://genderize.io/#ratelimiting ) to view how many API calls you have used / remaining / and time until reset.

From your terminal window you can use:

```
curl -i https://api.genderize.io/?name=kim
```

Then you should get a response similar to:

```
X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 1000 // The amount of names in the current time window
X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 738 // The number of names left in the current time window
X-Rate-Reset: 13829 // Seconds remaining until a new time window opens
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
!pip install gender_guesser    
import gender_guesser.detector as gender
names.gender = " " #Create a blank column to hold gender data
d = gender.Detector()
for i in range(len(names)):
  names.gender[i] = d.get_gender(names[i])
```